# Is it possible to run httpd as non-root with only a simple config file?

Tags: macos, apache, httpd.conf

Edit: I've been asked to state a concrete problem I'm looking for a solution for:

I'm using Apache `httpd` on Mac.

I want to run a local web server on port 2784.

I want it to use ~/foo as the Web root.

I want to do this as a non-root user.

I'm looking for the config file and/or command-line options to accomplish this, like so:

`$ httpd --foo 2784 --bar ~/foo`

What is --foo and --bar in this case, or if an external config file is needed, what is in it?

---

I am exploring different options to use for the "local dev test" web serveer for my project, which only requires serving static HTML.

I would like to avoid requiring extra packages for running it, and on Mac, the built-in `httpd` seems so obvious...

But so far, I have not been able to get it to work by running it from the command-line. On GNU/Linux, I have been "cheating" and installing `lighttpd`, which can be run with a short bare-bones config.

Is there an example of a minimum required to run config for Apache `httpd` out there?

I would really like to know.

Comment: I have looked at the similar question for Centos from 4+ years ago, and it helps, but I feel like it is not complete (and is also not Mac-specific). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422226/how-to-run-apache-as-non-root-using-non-standard-ports

Comment: Please check [help/on-topic] and [ask] and edit your question to contain a _concrete_ problem, observation, and intended behavior. The way it's currently asked is off-topic, asking for documentation (or similar). And "the minimum" config for Apache httpd depends on what you need. Most likely, it's what is already installed. If that's not enough, we'd need to know what doesn't work for you